# Java Generics - Confusing behavior

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting a compilation error here. Let me share some simple code. The following block of code works fine:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[0];
    MethodA(arr);
  }

  public static <E> void MethodA(E[] array) {
    Integer[] intArray = new Integer[0];
    MethodB(array, intArray);
  }

  public static <E> void MethodB(E[] array, E[] secondArray) {
    //Stuff
  }
}
```

The problem arises when I add a new generic List parameter to MethodB, calling it from MethodA:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[0];
    MethodA(arr);
  }

  public static <E> void MethodA(E[] array) {
    Integer[] intArray = new Integer[0];
    List<E> someList = new ArrayList<E>();
    MethodB(array, intArray, someList);
  }

  public static <E> void MethodB(E[] array, E[] secondArray, List<E> list) {
    //Stuff
  }
}
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       The method MethodB(E[], E[], List) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (E[], Integer[], List)

It seems to be telling me to change the parameter from E[] to Integer[], which is weird because it did not complain about such a thing until after I introduced the List parameter. Again, I feel like I must be making a silly mistake somewhere, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You're only passing two arguments into MethodB which looks like it requires 3 parameters.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo on my part when posting here - not related to my compilation problem. Thanks for the catch and sorry for any confusion!

Comment: Are you intending for `E` to be inferred as the widest common type shared by both `array` and `secondArray`? That doesn't seem very useful -- why not just take two `Object[]` arrays? Put another way: can you explain more about the `//Stuff` you're trying to do here?

Comment: The `E`s in each of your generic methods are completely independent. One type parameter = one type bound.

Comment: To debug stuff like this, I'd recommend calling generic methods with explicit type parameters. It can get hard if you're not sure what type is being inferred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first example, you're calling `MethodB` with a `String[]` and an `Integer[]`.

Since arrays are "covariant" - meaning, for example, you can cast a `String[]` to an `Object[]`, it calls the version of `MethodB` with `Object` for E.

In the second example, it's similar, but you also have a `List<E>`. Generic classes do *not* work the same way of arrays - you *cannot* cast a `List<String>` to a `List<Object>`. So it would be invalid for E to be `Object` (or anything other than whatever E is in `MethodA`) since then the third parameter couldn't be converted, and it would also be invalid for E to be `String` since then the first parameter couldn't be converted. So there is no type that works for `E`.

Note: If you changed `String` to `Integer` in `main`, it still wouldn't compile, even though `E` could be `Integer`. That's because the compiler doesn't know that `MethodA` is never called with anything other than `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

In method B declaration You use the same generic type(E) for all three parameters.
It meens that you may use a parameter of any kind (E) but it must be the same for all 3 parameters.

Try adding another generic type(T) like this:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[0];
    MethodA(arr);
  }

  public static <E> void MethodA(E[] array) {
    Integer[] intArray = new Integer[0];
    List<E> someList = new ArrayList<E>();
    MethodB(array, intArray, someList);
  }

  public static <E, T> void MethodB(E[] array, T[] secondArray, List<E> list) {
    //Stuff
  }
}
```

Or if there is a need you can add third so that List does not require the E to be the same type as in E[] array.

Answer (score 0):

MethodB requires all three parameters be of same type. But you are calling it with E and Integer. Try E[] intArray = null; and compiler will not compalin

Comment: Why does it not complain originally, before my introduction of the List parameter to methodB? Thanks.