# Generics Method Argument Behavior

Tags: java, generics, methods, collections

Consider a generic method program below:

```
class GenericTest {
    int i;
}
public class GenericMethod {

    public <T> List<T> addList(T t, T t1) {
        List<T> list=new ArrayList<T>();
        list.add(t);
        list.add(t1);
        return list;
    }
    public <T> List<T> addList(T t, T t1, List<T> l) {
        List<T> list=new ArrayList<T>();
        list.add(t);
        list.add(t1);
        list.addAll(l);
        return list;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericMethod gm=new GenericMethod();
        List l=gm.addList(new Integer(42), "java");           //Line 21
        System.out.println(l);
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        list.add(false);
        List l2 = gm.addList("java", new Integer(42), list);     //Line 25
        System.out.println(l2);
        GenericTest gt = new GenericTest();
        List l3 = gm.addList("java", gt);          //Line 28
        System.out.println(l3);
        List l4 = gm.addList(gm, gt);              //Line 30
        System.out.println(l4);
        List lst = new ArrayList();
        lst.add(new Object());
        List l5 = gm.addList("java", new Integer(42), lst);    //Line 34
        System.out.println(l5);
        System.out.println(l5.get(0));
    }
}
```

By going through the Reference link [Java Generics - Confusing behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336993/java-generics-confusing-behavior) I am infering that,

In Line 21 since the method is called with both String and Integer, it calls the method with Object for T. Same goes for Line 25 as List has also type Object, it calls the method with Object for T. Calling List with other type will produce an error. Is my inference correct?

What I cannot thought is about

1) Line 28 when String and class is passed,

2) Line 30 when two different class is passed,

3) Line 34 when List declared without type is passed as argument.

Can anyone share their knowledge to clear my understanding. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can clearly understand all of that if you stop using raw types and figure out what data type are your lists of... On the other hand, all your method calls are pretty easy to interpret using the number of arguments in terms of which one maps to which `addList` method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Calling List with other type will produce an error. Is my inference correct?

Yes; you cannot pass a `List<String>` there, for example. Generally the intent of your second addList method is just wrong. The correct signature is this:

```
public <T> List<T> addList(T t1, T t2, List<? extends T> list)
```

note the `? extends` syntax. If all you do is read from the list, there's no reason not to add that. A List of some specific subtype of T is guaranteed to contain Ts. The reason there's a difference at all: What if you wanted to *ADD* to this list? Let's say T is `Number` and you pass in a list of `Integer`. Double is a number. With `List<T> list` you could call `list.add(5.0)` and it would compile and run, putting doubles into your list of integers. With a `List<? extends T>`, the add call is always a compiler error (unless you try to add `null` which would work). For reading, you get a `T` out, whether you're calling `get` on a `List<? extends T>` or a `List<T>`, it does not matter.

> 1) Line 28 when String and class is passed,

No, you're passing an instance of type String and an instance of type GenericTest. String is just as much a class as GenericTest is. String is not special. This is exactly the same scenario as your call in line 21: You're passing 2 expressions; one of object type X and the other of object type Y. Therefore, `T` is inferenced to be the most specific shared type (possibly, a so-called lub type: A set of types) between the 2 passed instances. In the case of line 21, `Integer` and `String` most specific shared type is simply `Object` (to be technical, actually its the lub type `Object & Serializable`, but that mostly doesn't matter here). In line 28 it's the most specific shared type between `String` and `GenericTest` which is still `Object`, no difference.

> 2) Line 30 when two different class is passed,

See above; precisely the same situation. The most specific shared type between `GenericTest` and `GenericMethod` is `Object`.

> 3) Line 34 when List declared without type is passed as argument.

The expression `lst` in line 34 is of 'raw' type `ArrayList`. when you use raw types, two things happen: [1] the compiler will warn you that you're using raw types, and [2] pretty much all generics tests and checks are disabled for any calls that involve any raw types, so, the compiler will just let this happen.

Remember, generics are a figment of the compiler's imagination. Their point is for the compiler to tell you that your code is broken. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

In general, try to should avoid declaring `List` without a type parameter.  Even if you have to do `List<Object>`, it's more clear. (to both you and the compiler)

**Line 25** will not compile with a `String`, `Integer`, and `List<String>` because passing a `List<String>` will specifically cause the compiler to assume that `<T>` is a `String`.

`List l2 = gm.addList("java", new Integer(42), new ArrayList<Object>());     // compiles`

`List l2 = gm.addList("java", new Integer(42), new ArrayList<String>());     // does not compile`

You *could* change the declaration for `addList` to:

`public <T> List<T> addList(T t, T t1, List<? extends T> l) {`

Then both examples will compile.  The type parameter on the `List` parameter is no longer fixed to strictly `T`, but rather `T` or a supertype of `T`.  The compiler reasons that the type parameter is `Object`, since `Object` is a super-type of `String` (and the other parameters) the code compiles.

**Line 28, line 30, and line 34** are returning `List<Object>` as far as the compiler is concerned.  The only common type `T` that can be shared among the parameters is `Object`, so the compiler infers that `T` is `Object`.

As far as the JVM at run-time is concerned, there are no type parameters due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and they're all just `List`.  The type parameters are not present at run-time.